# How can I modify this script to get count at every 3 minutes?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to modify this query to get result for every 3 minutes interval i.e. 09:00 - 09:02 and 09:03 - 09:06

**Below Query gives output count for every 1 minute:**

```
select TO_CHAR(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), count(1) count
from emcdu.ext_contract_history ech
where ch_status='a' and CH_VALIDFROM BETWEEN TO_DATE('21/11/2018 
09:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
AND TO_DATE ('21/11/2018 09:06:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')--and 
ECH.CHANNEL='DSP'
and ch_validfrom=(select min(CH_VALIDFROM) from emcdu.ext_contract_history 
where co_id=ech.co_id and ch_status='a')
group by channel, TO_CHAR(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') ORDER BY 
TO_CHAR(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') ASC;
```

**Output for above query:**

```
TO_CHAR(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')         COUNT
11/21/2018 09:00                                       1
11/21/2018 09:01                                       2
11/21/2018 09:02                                       1
11/21/2018 09:03                                       1
11/21/2018 09:05                                       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select trunc(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM, 'mi') -  1/24/60 * mod(extract (minute from 
cast(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM as timestamp), 3), count(1) count
from emcdu.ext_contract_history ech
where ch_status='a' and CH_VALIDFROM BETWEEN TO_DATE('21/11/2018 
09:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
AND TO_DATE ('21/11/2018 09:06:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')--and 
ECH.CHANNEL='DSP'
and ch_validfrom=(select min(CH_VALIDFROM) from emcdu.ext_contract_history 
where co_id=ech.co_id and ch_status='a')
group by channel, trunc(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM, 'mi') -  1/24/60 * mod(extract (minute from 
cast(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM as timestamp)), 3) 
ORDER BY 
trunc(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM, 'mi') -  1/24/60 * mod(extract (minute from 
cast(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM as timestamp)), 3) ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below

```
select trunc(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM, 'mi') -  1/24/60 * mod(extract (minute from cast(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM as timestamp), 3), count(1) count
from emcdu.ext_contract_history ech
where ch_status='a' and CH_VALIDFROM BETWEEN TO_DATE('21/11/2018 
09:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
AND TO_DATE ('21/11/2018 09:06:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')--and 
ECH.CHANNEL='DSP'
and ch_validfrom=(select min(CH_VALIDFROM) from emcdu.ext_contract_history 
where co_id=ech.co_id and ch_status='a')
group by channel, trunc(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM, 'mi') -  1/24/60 * mod(extract (minute from cast(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM as timestamp)), 3) 
ORDER BY 
trunc(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM, 'mi') -  1/24/60 * mod(extract (minute from cast(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM as timestamp)), 3) ASC;
```

Comment: Hi @fa06,
Thansk for your answer, but I am getting below error:
ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

Comment: @Pawan, I've edited it again - you can check here - it's demo - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e6e345ad7af299a23c3151264f4370f